# Shopping Cart Software - Form Key Security

Tags: php, security, magento

I added a shopping cart button to my catalog list.phtml page using the following code which I saw suggested several places online:

```
<button type="button" style="(styles here)" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

It worked perfectly, but I then got chewed out by another web developer at my work because, in his words: "in your coding, you left a big security risk. you show the secret security key of the site. the form key is the 'code' to log into the database. in your coding you revealed it.'"

He was referring to HTML output that looks like `/form_key/SomeRandomString`.

I tried researching this (I'll admit I know little about website security) but I don't understand how the form key can also be used to "log in" to the Magento database. Isn't it a random string of numbers and letters that's unique to each user session? Can someone with experience explain this to me?

I'm using Magento EE 1.13.

Comment: I'm unclear on which part of this code would output anything like `form_key`, but you really should discuss this with the person who provided the feedback.

Comment: I looked up `form_key` and it appears to be a CSRF token. These are fine to include in the HTML - in fact, you *have* to provide them to the client side in some way. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/what-is-the-form-key-used-for

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I would ask him but he does remote work and every time I contact him for anything he complains about how I'm causing him extra work, so I would like to restrict our contact to what's strictly necessary to do my job. I'm just really confused about why he said what he said and would like to know if there's any validity to it at all.

Comment: I'd suggest it's time to escalate that issue to a mutual manager.

Comment: What would you suggest telling the manager? Sorry if these questions seem stupid. I've never been in this situation before.

Comment: I'd suggest https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ for that. I believe there are some questions along this line there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.